# How to iterate over a series of numbers passed as arguments to a bash function and then return a count of even numbers?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#this function checks if a number is even
#checks only 1 argument

function isiteven {
 if [[ $1%2 -eq 0 ]]
 then
  echo "1"
 else
  echo "0"
 fi 
}
```

I need to use this file as source to another file and create a function that returns the count of even numbers passed to a function called 'nevens'.

I tried this code:

```
source program6.sh

function nevens {
for check in $@
 do
  if [[ -e isiteven$# ]]
  then
   let count=count+1
  fi
 done

echo $count
}
```

I am confused what shell sign to use to iterate in for loop and to check in if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're outputting a `0` or a `1` from `isiteven`, you can just unconditionally add the output of the function:

```
#!/bin/bash

source program6.sh

function nevens {
  local count=0
  for check; do # implicit `for check in "$@"`
    (( count += $(isiteven $check) )) # add output of `isiteven $check`
  done
  echo $count
}
```

This assumes that your input is all valid, so if that's not guaranteed to be the case, you will need to add some checks.

Note that this script uses several non-standard features that won't work in all shells:

- `source program6.sh` instead of the standard `. program6.sh`
- `function` keyword instead of just `nevens () {`
- `local` keyword to declare a local variable inside the function
- `+=`, instead of the standard `count=$(( count + $(isiteven $check) ))`

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your response. This works perfectly.
I just wanted to ask that is it okay to declare count as local?

Comment: Yeah, you can declare it as a local variable no problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: Even shorter: `n=0; for arg; do n=$((n+(arg%2==0))); done; echo $n`